# Dependencies problems installing openjdk on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, apt, openjdk

I try to install openjdk-7-jre:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
```

But I have dependencies problems:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 openjdk-7-jre : Depends: openjdk-7-jre-headless (= 7u7-2.3.2a-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libgif4 (>= 4.1.4) but it is not installable
                 Depends: libatk-wrapper-java-jni (>= 0.30.4-0ubuntu2) but it is not installable
                 Recommends: libgnome2-0 but it is not installable
                 Recommends: libgnomevfs2-0 but it is not going to be installed
                 Recommends: ttf-dejavu-extra but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

This is version of Ubuntu:

```
Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS
```

I completely don't know how resolve dependencies...
Some one can help me?
Thank you for ahead.

Comment: it might be a bug:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tzdata/+bug/1212319

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so I just tried to install every dependency in dependencies tree, and most basic was:

```
tzdata-java_2012e-0ubuntu0.12.04_all.deb
```

I downloaded it from:

```
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tzdata/2012e-0ubuntu0.12.04/+build/3726497/+files/tzdata-java_2012e-0ubuntu0.12.04_all.deb
```

and typed:

```
sudo dpkg -i tzdata-java_2012e-0ubuntu0.12.04_all.deb
```

After again:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jre
```

And now it in the installation process.